# Web API 2 : Best Practice returning ViewModel data from Controller to $http Success result ?

Tags: c#, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I wonder what's the recommended way to handle data (ViewModels) in Web Api 2.. I have googled around quite much, and found some "recepies" but i wonder what's the most flexible and easy way of handling this..

This call returns error -->

```
GET http://localhost:63203/api/Gallery/GetPhotosForPage 404 (Not Found)
```

probably because of some signature error..,.

Here is the $http call (Angular) :

```
var currPage = $location.path() || "Unknown"; 

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/Gallery/GetPhotosForPage',
    accept: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(currPage)   //currpage = ex. "/leftwing"
    })
        .success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.mystuff= result;
        });
```

Here is the Controller GET method : /PriPhotosModel is the viewmodel...

```
[HttpGet]
    public object GetPhotosForPage(string currPage)
    {
        PhotoServices photoService = new PhotoServices();
        List<PriPhotosModel> priPhotos = photoService.GetPriPhotosForAllPhotographersOnPage(currPage);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, priPhotos);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that **WebApi** works based on reflection this means that your curly braces {vars} must match the same name in your methods.

Therefore to match a sample URL like `api/gallery/test` based on the default template  `"api/{controller}/{id}"` Your method needs to be declared like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetPhotosForPage(string id){
   return id;
}
```

Where the parameter `string currPage` was replaced by `string id`.

The reason why is because the default routing declares the parameter with name **`id`**  :

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
                 routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                 defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Web Api v1 defines resources globally in the **global.asax** on **application_start** event. Assuming you are using Visual Studio 2013 and based Microsoft default template your method may look like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

The WebApi routing configuration occurs in the `WebApiConfig.Register` while the MVC configuration occurs in the  `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`

Regarding WebApi v2 which introduced something called **Route Attributes** those can be used along with your Controller class and can facilitate the routing configuration.

For example:

```
 public class BookController : ApiController{
     //where author is a letter(a-Z) with a minimum of 5 character and 10 max.      
    [Route("sample/{id}/{newAuthor:alpha:length(5,10)}")]
    public Book Get(int id, string newAuthor){
        return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + newAuthor };
    }

   [Route("otherUrl/{id}/{newAuthor:alpha:length(5,10)}/{title}")]
   public Book Get(int id, string newAuthor, string title){
       return new Book() { Title = "SQL Server 2012 id= " + id, Author = "Adrian & " + newAuthor };
   }
...
```

Comment: Wow!.. Thanks a bunch for your very detailed and understandable answer Dalorzo :) 

This gave me a brief understanding of some things i have still yet to learn about Routing and such... 

but.. i also wonder how you would send over parameters from the client ($http call) to a controller method as best practice if you have a string or an int or whatever you want to send to the GET method on the server.. 

Cause.. public object GetPhotosForPage(string currPage) should only be called like this right ? -->  url: '/api/Gallery/GetPhotosForPage', with data: currPage (string) ? '

Comment: if you use property from Javascript Ajax it means that is most likely a `Post` method call then your method in WebApi needs to marked as `[HttpPost]` method as well and one of your parameters will be `[FromBody]`

Comment: Ah! That might be the trick :) still possible to return a viewmodel then i guess ? :)

Comment: From your sample above I do not see a reason why not.