# Execute a simple call to a WebAPI Get using RestRequest and a single string parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following code in my receiving controller:

```
[Route("api/StudentUserId/{string}"), HttpGet]
public StudentDto StudentUserId(string userId)
    {
        StudentModel sm = new StudentModel(userId);
        StudentDto dto = sm.ConvertToDto();
        return dto;
    }
```

After running this project, I have another project that I use to test the WebAPI controller calls.  I use the following code to read a student record form the database using their userId:

```
protected T SendRequestToReadItemUsingString<T>(string resource, string userId) where T : new()
{
    string resourceString = string.Format("{0}/{{userId}}", resource);
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest(resourceString, Method.GET);
    request.AddUrlSegment("userId", userId);
    RestClient restClient = new RestClient(Service.Location);
    var response = restClient.Execute<T>(request);

    T retVal = response.Data;
    return retVal;
}
```

Comparible code seems to work if I change the userId to an int Id in both the controller and calling code.  I can't seem to get it to work with string.  If I place a breakpoint in the controller code it never hits it and the calling code just returns a null.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that **WebApi** works based on reflection this means that your curly braces {vars} must match the same name in your methods.

Therefore to match this `api/StudentUserId/{string}` your method needs to be declare like this:

```
   [Route("api/StudentUserId/{userId}"), HttpGet]
   public StudentDto StudentUserId(string userId)
       return userId;
   }
```

Where the parameter `{string}` was replaced by `userId`.

If you want to read more about this Routing Rules here is similar post on this;

[WebApi Routing Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570797/1959948)