# Why won't my call to a Web API route to the correct method?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have my first Web API working, but the even when I call it and pass an an id is gets routed to the method that has no arguments.

Here is my controller code:

```
public class ChartController : ApiController
{
    Chart[] _charts = new Chart[] 
    { 
        new Chart { Name = "Chart 1" }, 
        new Chart { Name = "Chart 2" }, 
        new Chart { Name = "Chart 3" }
    };

    // GET api/chart
    [Route("api/chart")]
    public IEnumerable<Chart> Get()
    {
        return _charts;
    }

    // GET api/chart/{id}
    [Route("api/chart/{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<Chart> Get(int chartId)
    {
        Chart[] charts = new Chart[]
        {
            Charts.Database.ChartsDB.GetChart(chartId)
        };

        return charts;
    }

}
```

Here is my routing in my global.asax

```
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ChartApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

This is my request uri

```
http://localhost:42311/api/chart
```

And the results

```
[
{
    "Name": "Chart 1"
},
{
    "Name": "Chart 2"
},
{
    "Name": "Chart 3"
}
```

]

When I change the uri to

```
http://localhost:42311/api/chart/1
```

I get the same results, as both calls are routed to

```
public IEnumerable<Chart> Get()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that **WebApi** works based on reflection this means that your curly braces {vars} must match the same name in your methods.

Therefore to match this `api/chart/{id}` your method needs to be declare like this:

```
   [Route("api/chart/{chartId}"), HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<Chart> Get(int chartId)
       return userId;
   }
```

Where the parameter `{id}` was replaced by `chartId`.

Another option can be:

```
 [Route("api/chart/{id}"), HttpGet]
 public IEnumerable<Chart> Get(int id)
   return userId;
 }
```

If you want to read more about this Routing Rules here is similar post on this;

[WebApi Routing Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570797/1959948)

Comment: Spot on.  Thanks Dalorzo.